# Deploy multiple application package on same container in vespa

Tags: docker, bigdata, vespa

I have downloaded sample vespa apps from git clone https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps.git. I have created same application like **basic-search** which I named **location**. Now I want to deploy both application on same container using below steps:

To deploy **basic-search** application:

sudo docker run --detach --name vespa1 --hostname vespa-container --privileged --volume $VESPA_SAMPLE_APPS:/vespa-sample-apps --publish 8080:8080 vespaengine/vespa

sudo docker exec vespa1 bash -c 'curl --head http://localhost:19071/ApplicationStatus'

sudo docker exec vespa1 bash -c '/opt/vespa/bin/vespa-deploy prepare /vespa-sample-apps/basic-search/src/main/application/ && /opt/vespa/bin/vespa-deploy activate'

curl -s --head http://localhost:8080/ApplicationStatus

To deploy **location** application:

sudo docker run --detach --name vespa2 --hostname vespa-container --privileged --volume $VESPA_SAMPLE_APPS:/vespa-sample-apps --publish 8081:8081 vespaengine/vespa

sudo docker exec vespa2 bash -c 'curl --head http://localhost:19071/ApplicationStatus'

sudo docker exec vespa2 bash -c '/opt/vespa/bin/vespa-deploy prepare /vespa-sample-apps/location/src/main/application/ && /opt/vespa/bin/vespa-deploy activate'

curl -s --head http://localhost:8081/ApplicationStatus

First application is deployed successfully but in second one I am getting this error: Command failed. No directory or zip file found: '/vespa-sample-apps/location/src/main/application/'

Comment: The `--name` argument with two different values (`vespa1` and `vespa2`) tends to say that you run in two different containers, aren't you ?

Comment: So what should I do to deploy both application in same container?Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?Also, please upvote my question if you feel suitable.

Comment: It'zs just that the name of the question is misleading, because you do not "deploy multiple application package on same container in vespa" you try to launch two Vespa containers and to deploy different applications on those two containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy second application, I need to publish it with 8081|8080. Because vespa-container is running on 8080 and I was trying to running on 8081 port.After running with 8081 on localhost and vespa-container on 8080 it works.Now I am able to deploy multiple apllications with multiple ports.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you'd need to assign different ports to all the processes of each of the applications using the "baseport" concept. However, it is much simpler to use different Docker containers for different applications instead. This also provides the resource isolation you'll want between different applications.

Note that if it's really different functionality belonging to the same application you can set up multiple separate clusters in the same application (in the same services.xml file), or alternatively just add multiple schemas and so on to the same clusters.